# Python: How do I generate a random matrix of 1.0 and 0.0, but with floats?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, random

I am currently coding Conway's game of life and to add randomization to my world I have implemented a function to create a random matrix with 1 and 0 with n rows and n columns.

The problem is that, for my code to work, I need a random matrix of 1 and 0 but they have to be floats, so 0.0 and 1.0
So I cannot use:

```
rand_matrix = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, size=n)
```

Instead I have tried:

```
n = 10 
one_zero = [0.0,1.0]
rand_matrix = np.array([n*[random.choice(one_zero),random.choice(one_zero)],n*[random.choice(one_zero),random.choice(one_zero)]])
```

Getting:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]]
```

But this returns a matrix of different dimensions, what I want is a random n by n matrix. And each row should be a combination of 0.0 and 1.0 randomly chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10)).astype(float)
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast the `randint()` matrix to float:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = 10
>>> rand_matrix = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n, n)).astype(float)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
>>>
```